# Excel File Disappear in Excel WebPart

Tags: web-part, excel

I created excel web part. The webpart worked properly. But now, it isn't work. I got this error. I controlled excel file, it opened. But it disappear in webpart.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to open using Chrome or Internet Explorer. ?

Comment: I tried, but I got same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your excel settings.

Go to File > Excel Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings

You may find clue for the problem.

I had similar issue using Excel and found the solution after i start to explore the Excel security settings.